# Jboss service suddenly not starting without errors

Tags: jboss

I am new to Jboss. I have using a Jboss server on ubuntu to generate PKI certificates that has been runing for last 5 years without any issues. However last week it stopped working. The standalone.sh script executes without errors but the total number of services that are running is reduced and am not able to generate any certificates using ecbca.sh script.

When it was operational:

10:48:57,082 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) started in 136517ms - Started 2806 of 2843 services (101 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

And now:

8:06:25,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) started in 4104ms - Started 168 of 206 services (63 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
1

Furthermore am not able to log into the web admin gui.

```
    DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) Configured system properties:
    [Standalone] = 
awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
file.encoding = UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
file.separator = /
java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.headless = true
java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
java.class.path = /home/user/jboss-eap-6.4/jboss-modules.jar
java.class.version = 52.0
java.endorsed.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12
java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version = 1.8
java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version = 1.8.0_162
java.vm.info = mixed mode
java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version = 25.162-b12
javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
jboss.home.dir = /home/user/jboss-eap-6.4
jboss.host.name = MyHost
jboss.modules.dir = /home/user/jboss-eap-6.4/modules
jboss.modules.policy-permissions = true
jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
jboss.node.name = MyHost
jboss.qualified.host.name = MyHost
jboss.server.base.dir = /home/user/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone
jboss.server.config.dir = /home/user/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/configuration
jboss.server.data.dir = /home/user/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/data
jboss.server.deploy.dir = /home/user/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/data/content
jboss.server.log.dir = /home/user/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/log
jboss.server.name = MyHost
jboss.server.persist.config = true
jboss.server.temp.dir = /home/user/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/tmp
line.separator =
```

Can you please let me know what are the checks that I need to do.

Thanks

Hassan

I performed a "ps -ax | grep java" and then a "kill -9 xxx"

Comment: You'd want to look at the failures in the logs. Up the log from the services message. However, what it looks like is the second message is missing the deployment or other configurations.